# powershell calling function to return a value

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script for foldercleanup. I want key value ($key) to be returned by a function called passval ,which is a separate file. but its not passing.
This is the function

```
  function passval{$s="cleanupfolder"
               $s
              return $s}
```

This is the main code

```
$colItems = (Get-ChildItem D:\00Newfolder  -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
    "{0:N2}" -f ($colItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB"
    $xxx="{0:N2}" -f ($colItems.sum/ 1MB)
    $str=Get-Content D:\trial.txt | ConvertFrom-Csv

    "This is the function passed value" 
     $key = passval
     echo $key

    $flag=0

    for($i=0; $i -lt $str.length; $i++){

    if($str[$i].key -eq $key){
    $flag=1
    $flag
    $value=$str[$i].value



    }
    }

    $flag

    if($flag -eq 0){$a = new-object -comobject wscript.shell

    $b = $a.popup(“no match" )}

    if($flag -eq 1){$a = new-object -comobject wscript.shell

    $b = $a.popup(“ match" )}             


    if($xxx -gt $value){Remove-Item  D:\00Newfolder\*   -include *.jpg}

    $colItems = (Get-ChildItem D:\00Newfolder  -recurse | Measure-Object -property length -sum)
    "{0:N2}" -f ($colItems.sum / 1MB) + " MB"
    $xxx="{0:N2}" -f ($colItems.sum/ 1MB)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where is your `passval` function defined? It has to be defined before it's called. And as it's now it will return your value twice, change it to:

```
function passval
{
     $s="cleanupfolder"               
     return $s
}
```

And on a side note: work on you formatting and naming. In powershell your function should be called something like `Get-PassValue`